# Trying to create Rails "application" in the Beginning Ruby: From Novice to Professional book but stuck on one bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In the Beginning Ruby: From Novice to Professional book Chapter 13 focuses on the frameworks that were most popular at the time of the writing; Rails, of course, featuring prominently.

The project that is used to introduce the concepts has a section which extends the generic application created with the rails command by adding a view_all method to the scaffold:

```
def view_all
  @Entries = Entry.all(:order => 'created_at DESC')
end
```

It also points out that the config/routes.rb file contains the following:

```
map.resources :entries
```

and to update to be

```
map.resources :entries, :collection => { :view_all => :get }
```

The problem is that my config/routes.rb file does not look exactly like that. It does not have the `map.` portion and just looks like

```
resources :entries
```

I added the `:collection...` portion anyway.

The book then says to add the following to app/views/entries/view_all.html.erb

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
  <h1><%= entry.title %></h1>
  <p><%= entry.content %></p>
  <p><em>Posted at <%= entry.created_at %></em></p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Add New entry', new_entry_path %>
```

I've done all of this, but when I attempt to run the "application" I get an error

```
Couldn't find Entry with id=view_all
```

with the parameters as

```
{"collection"=>{"view_all"=>:get},
 "id"=>"view_all"}
```

Has anyone else either looked at the book and seen how it is a bit out of date and know a fix for this or at least have a general understanding of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you start with rails, I would recommend to use the latest version..your version seems to be rails 2.xx and the latest is 4.0.0. - so there are two major releases between..definitly use the newest one! Better search for a new beginner guide like guides.rubyonrails.org..

Answer (score 1):

That book you are referring to is using older version of Rails.

In Rails 2, the syntax(as you've shown):

```
map.resources :entries, :collection => { :view_all => :get }
```

In Rails 3, the syntax is:

```
resources :entries do
  get :view_all, on: :collection
end
```

**Update:**

Managed to grab the E-book version of second edition of the book and yes the second edition is using Rails 2.3.2.  I think you should work on to find a newer book for yourself since you're using Rails 3 (based on the tag in question).

To get an understanding of routes, I think [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) document is pretty verbose.